# HTML: Stop pictures from overlap on mobile view (responsive design)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I've got a website, based on wordpress and the responsive design "Mystile".

I use the following html code to display three pictures side by side:

```
<div style="position: absolute;"><a href="myhref"><img src="myimgsrc" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 250px;"><a href="myhref"><img src="myimgsrc" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 500px;"><a href="myhref"><img src="myimgsrc" alt="" /></a></div>
```

This works flawlessly on the computer.
As you can see on the picture.

[image]

But on a mobile device it looks terrible.
Like this:

[image]

What can should I do?
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want a "responsive design" don't use absolute position or fixed `px` values for margin like that.

Comment: [**http://learnlayout.com/**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Okay. My wordpress theme is automatically making a responsive design. How should my code look like that it works on the computer and the mobile view? Thanks.

Comment: It's not that simple you need to start with the basic of responsive and media queries

Comment: Your wordpress theme is NOT responsive.. in simple terms.

Comment: Okay Lee. But it automatically adapts the size of all the content when you're using the website on a device with a smaller display. Isn't this responsive? But that does not really matter. My question is, if somebody can help me to rewrite the code that the pictures get displayed properly on the computer and the mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is just to display the images inline. They will then wrap under each other if there isn't enough space to fit beside one another:

```css
html, body {margin:0;}
.hmm a {display:inline-block; margin:10px 0 0 10px;}
.hmm a img {display:block; margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class="hmm"><a href="myhref"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/240x50" alt="placeholder" /></a><a href="myhref"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/240x50" alt="placeholder" /></a><a href="myhref"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/240x50" alt="placeholder" /></a></div>
```

---

If you want to get a little more advanced you can use [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to change the style for different sized viewports:

```css
html, body {margin:0;}
.hmm a {display:inline-block; margin:10px 0 0 10px;}
.hmm a img {display:block; margin:0;}

@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
  .hmm a:first-of-type img {width:490px;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 510px) {
  .hmm a {
      display: block;
      margin:10px;
  }    
  .hmm a img {
      width:100%!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hmm"><a href="myhref"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/240x50" alt="placeholder" /></a><a href="myhref"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/240x50" alt="placeholder" /></a><a href="myhref"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/240x50" alt="placeholder" /></a></div>
```

^ Go 'full-page' and resize to see this one working.

Comment: Great, thanks! This works perfect. Can you tell me where I can define the distance between the pictures?

Comment: Yeah, just change the `margin`. You'll see I've given them a 10px top and left margin.